# how to add a godaddy ssl certificate to a site hosted on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, elastic-load-balancer, a-records

how to add a godaddy ssl certificate to a site hosted on aws ec2 (linux - apache) with domain purchased on bigrock and and A-record pointing from the bigrock console to the Elastic IP of the EC2-instance

Answer (score 0):

You can include the PEM encoded SSL certificate(If the certificate is in different encoding, you can convert it to PEM encoded format) from Godaddy to the AWS Load Balancer. If you don't use a Load Balancer, you can install the SSL certificate to the Apache Server(You can download the certificate for Apache format from Godaddy) running in EC2 instance.

Comment: I tried to install it to the apache server. Changed the SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateChainFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile parameters in the ssl.conf file and restarted the server. It is not working. Also, tried to use a load balancer (classic load balancer). Not sure how to connect the load balancer when the A record is present in the bigrock console

Comment: If you are using the load balancer, you need to point a CName to Load Balancer from Godaddy and to install the certificate to the LB, you need to upload it to AWS Certificate Manger and then assign it to the LB.

If you are directly installing, make sure the encoding is right, mostly the mistake happens in encoding. As I can remember for Apache you need to pem encoded certificate.

Comment: I've completed process of importing certificate and associating LB with the certificate.How to get the load-balancer's IP to point CNAME to it ? Also, should I now remove my Elastic IP now that I have a LB ?